# Transforming large Xml files

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, out-of-memory

I was using this extension method to transform very large xml files with an xslt.

Unfortunately, I get an OutOfMemoryException on the source.ToString() line.

I realize there must be a better way, I'm just not sure what that would be?

```
public static XElement Transform(this XElement source, string xslPath, XsltArgumentList arguments)
{
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(source.ToString());

        var xsl = new XslCompiledTransform();
        xsl.Load(xslPath);

        using (var swDocument = new StringWriter(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            using (var xtw = new XmlTextWriter(swDocument))
            {
                xsl.Transform((doc.CreateNavigator()), arguments, xtw);
                xtw.Flush();
                return XElement.Parse(swDocument.ToString());
            }
        }
}
```

Thoughts?  Solutions?  Etc.

UPDATE:
Now that this is solved, I have issues with validating the schema!
[Validating large Xml files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884966/validating-large-xml-files)

Comment: How large is very large?

Comment: I've already found changing *doc.LoadXml(source.ToString());* to *doc.Load(source.CreateReader());* helps...not sure what it's limits are though.

Comment: @Rob Goodwin, 50MB, and that's only 1 record...likely this will have more.

Comment: The BIG problem is that you have at the same time an XElement and an XmlDocument -- this is twice the memory you'd need if you used only XmlDocument. My advice is not to use LINQ (or somehow to get rid of the LINQ objects before you create the XmlDocument). Using XPathDocument instead of XmlDocument could also help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.Xml.Xsl;

static class Extensions
{
    public static XElement Transform(
        this XElement source, string xslPath, XsltArgumentList arguments)
    {
        var xsl = new XslCompiledTransform();
        xsl.Load(xslPath);

        var result = new XDocument();
        using (var writer = result.CreateWriter())
        {
            xsl.Transform(source.CreateNavigator(), arguments, writer);
        }
        return result.Root;
    }
}
```

BTW, `new XmlTextWriter()` is deprecated as of .NET 2.0. Use `XmlWriter.Create()` instead. Same with `new XmlTextReader()` and `XmlReader.Create()`.

Comment: Thanks, this works great!  I've added a follow up question related to validating (xsd) 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884966/validating-large-xml-files

Answer (score 2):

For large XML files you can try to use XPathDocument as suggested in [Microsoft Knowledge Base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307494).

```
XPathDocument srcDoc = new XPathDocument(srcFile);
XslCompiledTransform myXslTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();
myXslTransform.Load(xslFile);
using (XmlWriter destDoc = XmlWriter.Create(destFile))
{
    myXslTransform.Transform(srcDoc, destDoc);
}
```