# Validating large Xml files

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

As a follow up to my issue [transforming large Xml files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884795/transforming-large-xml-files), I now need to validate the schema.

I was using this extension method, which can clearly be improved upon as it's not working correctly either

```
public static XElement ValidateXsd(this XElement source, string xsdPath)
{
    var errors = new XElement("Errors");

    // Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358456.aspx
    var xsd = XDocument.Load(xsdPath);
    var xml = XDocument.Load(source.CreateReader());

    var schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
    schemas.Add("", xsd.CreateReader());

    if (xml.Document != null)
    {
        xml.Document.Validate(schemas,
            // Validation Event/Error Handling
            (sender, e) =>
                {
                    var message = e.Message
                        .Replace(
                            "element is invalid - The value '' is invalid according to its datatype 'requiredString' - The actual length is less than the MinLength value.",
                            "cannot be blank.")
                        .Replace(
                            "is invalid according to its datatype 'size' - The Pattern constraint failed.",
                            "must be numeric.")
                        .Replace(
                            "element is invalid",
                            "is invalid.");

                    errors.Add(new XElement("Error", message));
                }
            );
    }

    // If there were errors return them, otherwise return null
    return errors.Elements().Count() > 0 ? errors : null;
}
```

Comment: What is the error?  Meaning are is this method throwing an exception if so what type?

Or are there errors then you are not getting them back?  

The answer might vary on the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
public static XElement ValidateXsd(this XElement source, string xsdPath)
{
    var errors = new XElement("Errors");

    // Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358456.aspx 

    var schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(xsdPath))
    {
        schemas.Add("", reader);
    }

    {
        source.Document.Validate(
            schemas,
            // Validation Event/Error Handling 
            (sender, e) =>
            {
                var message =
                    e.Message.Replace(
                        "element is invalid - The value '' is invalid according to its datatype 'requiredString' - The actual length is less than the MinLength value.",
                        "cannot be blank.").Replace(
                        "is invalid according to its datatype 'size' - The Pattern constraint failed.",
                        "must be numeric.").Replace("element is invalid", "is invalid.");

                errors.Add(new XElement("Error", message));
            });
    }

    // If there were errors return them, otherwise return null 
    return errors.Elements().Count() > 0 ? errors : null;
}
```

---

Try this instead:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Schema;

    static class Extensions
    {
        public static XElement ValidateXsd(this XElement source, string xsdPath)
        {
            var errors = new XElement("Errors");

            // Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358456.aspx 

            var schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
            using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(xsdPath))
            {
                schemas.Add("", reader);
            }

            var sourceQualifiedName = new XmlQualifiedName(source.Name.LocalName, source.Name.NamespaceName);
            source.Validate(
                schemas.GlobalElements[sourceQualifiedName],
                schemas,
                // Validation Event/Error Handling 
                (sender, e) =>
                {
                    var message =
                        e.Message.Replace(
                            "element is invalid - The value '' is invalid according to its datatype 'requiredString' - The actual length is less than the MinLength value.",
                            "cannot be blank.").Replace(
                            "is invalid according to its datatype 'size' - The Pattern constraint failed.",
                            "must be numeric.").Replace("element is invalid", "is invalid.");

                    errors.Add(new XElement("Error", message));
                });

            // If there were errors return them, otherwise return null 
            return errors.Elements().Count() > 0 ? errors : null;
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Would this work if you xsd is based on the element which is a subset of the source?

Comment: It will work or not, depending on whether it's valid to have a schema inside your source.

Comment: the problem I have with this is source.Document is null

Comment: @Sorry, I seem to have posted it twice.